# Creating a layout control available in design-time

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I wanted to create a sort of "layout" helper control. Using it would allow me to define content for several sections, and the control would be responsible for making sure the layout is consistent.

I'm doing this via `ContentPresenter` and `object` dependency properties.

The end result is that if I run the application, then the content I defined looks fine.

But in design-time? It's empty on the designer screen.

This is a major issue - whoever will be working on the actual content (be it me or anyone else) should be able to preview what they are doing without the constant need to fire up the application.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the sample code:

MainLayout.xaml (simplified)

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <!--layout related stuff-->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <!--layout related stuff-->
            <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Height="120" StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" />
            </Viewbox>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter" />
        </Grid>
```

MainLayout.cs (simplified - inherits `UserControl`)

```
    public object HeaderContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderContent", typeof(object), typeof(MainLayout), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => (d as MainLayout).HeaderContentPresenter.Content = e.NewValue));

    public object ButtonContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(object), typeof(MainLayout), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => (d as MainLayout).ButtonContentPresenter.Content = e.NewValue));
```

Usage example XAML:

```
<namespace:MainLayout>
  <namespace:MainLayout.HeaderContent>
    <TextBlock Text="This will be only visible once the app is started, but not in design-time" />
  </namespace:MainLayout.HeaderContent>
</namespace:MainLayout>
```

Please note - this is a Windows 8.1 (WinRT-XAML) related question. It may not have the same solution as a similar WPF problem.